# Java, regular expression involving the "{n} " quantifier

Tags: java

does anyone know why the following code accepts an answer such as `123-123-1234`:

`[1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{2}-\\d{4}`

I thought with the code, it only accepted **2 numbers first, 2 numbers** again and then **4 numbers**, like this:
`12-12-1234` <-- but this is invalid with the code `[1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{2}-\\d{4}`

I tested this by using the following:

```
    String numbers = "123-123-1234";

    if(numbers.matches("[1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{2}-\\d{4}")) {
        System.out.println("String object \"numbers\" is valid.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("String object \"numbers\" is invalid.");
    }
```

Thank you for feedback, if there isn't sufficient information in this post, please let me know.

Comment: Use Pattern class instead of matches function for prod use

Comment: @YatiSawhney - For a strictly one-time match, there's no performance advantage to using the Pattern class.

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe it, this makes so much sense now! Thank you so much guys! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @TedHopp It wouldn't. But it's hard for me to believe that an app will use it exactly once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Rick Measham's site](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) for explaining regular expressions:

`[1-9]\d{2}-[1-9]\d{2}-\d{4}`

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
```

Answer (score 3):

The subexpression (space inserted for readability):

```
[1-9] \d{2}
----- -----
  |     |
  |     + Two digits [0-9]
  +-- One digit [1-9]
```

by itself accepts THREE digits, but the first digit cannot be zero.

Answer (score 0):

- `[1-9]` matches a single character in the range between 1 to 9
- `\d{2}` matches a digit exactly 2 times
- `-` matches the character `-` one time

And for the next `[1-9]\d{2}-` the same as above, and the last

- `\d{4}` matches a digit exactly 4 times

so the RegEx `[1-9]\d{2}-[1-9]\d{2}-\d{4}` macthes 123-123-1234

Answer (score 0):

The expression `[1-9]\d{2}-[1-9]\d{2}-\d{4}` mean `A char in range 0 to 9` `two digits`-`A char in range 0-9` `two digits`-`four digits`.

The correct regex `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}` which translates to `two digits`-`two digits`-`four digits`

Equivalent java code `numbers.matches("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")`